# Sending an object from android to java using sockets (Hibernate class)

Tags: java, android, mysql, hibernate, sockets

I have created a class in java and connect it to MySql using `hibernate`,
to send the class via `sockets` it should implements `Serializable` and give it a `serialversionuid` .
Also to make it works I export the class as `.jar` file and included in both android an java projects .

The question here , since my class created in java call the hibernate Api such `@ColumnName("Bla")` , how should I make it work on android , since android project not included the hibernate library ?

Comment: If your class has any methods / functions, the class definition will need to be included on both your server and your android app. You should then be able to send it using ObjectInput/Output streams (or as JSON or XML) Otherwise, if it's essentially just data, I'd recommend sending it as JSON or XML.I am negative on Object serialization, as version control of objects on both sides can be a pain to manage. Transmission protocols (like XML and JSON as I've mention) that have been developed subsequent to Java Serialization, and they allow you to be platform agnostic

Comment: The problem is that my class have an attribute of type Byte[] , this attribute is actually an image converted to binary , if I want to send it using JSONObject for example , I will be obliged to converted to a string of base64 and this process will may take a lot of time due to the size of the image , I think it's  not recommended to make a process like this to work over the android app , it will be better to make it on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that It doesn't matter you can use the class even without include hibernate in your android , maybe the reason is because it's a .jar file.